# cant login or sign up to Unity Hub 3.1.1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just downloaded Unity 3.1.1, when i click the "Sign in" or "create account" button, it dosent do anything.

I had tried searching for tutorials or tips from Google, but i can't find anything related to my problem.

Comment: any resolution you have found?

Comment: Please specify with the major version number that seems to be `2020.3.1.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Win 10. My workaround was to run Unity Hub as administrator. Once I did that, the Sign In button started working.